# ¿Varios eventos con el mismo Click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

No tengo mucho conocimiento en JavaScript, sin embargo a veces intento hacer cosillas, la cosa es que tengo un evento que hace lo siguiente.

Al dar click agrega el producto al carrito y cierra un modal, es decir hace dos cosas a la vez, cierra el modal y agrega al carrito, valga la redundancia.

Lo que yo quiero es agregar un tercer evento, y que quede así.

1- Agrega el producto al carrito

2- Cierra el modal

3- Abre un menú lateral.

El menú lateral normalmente  lo llamo de esta forma desde un html

```
<a href="#" data-drawer-trigger="" aria-controls="drawer-name" aria-expanded="false">Abrir</a>
```

El evento en JavaScript o jquery es este

```
document.getElementById("addCitemCart").addEventListener("click", function() {
  $(".modal-close").click();
  updateC(customitem, 1, crate);
});
```

Intente hacerlo como mostraré a continuación pero nada que funciona.

```
document.getElementById("addCitemCart").addEventListener("click", function() {
  $(".modal-close").click();
  updateC('data-drawer-trigger="" aria-controls="drawer-name" aria-expanded="false');
});
```

Tambien he intentado hacerlo asi.

```
document.getElementById("addCitemCart").addEventListener("click", function() {
        $(".modal-close").click();
        updateC(customitem, 1, crate);
        window.location.href = 'data-drawer-trigger="" aria-controls="drawer-name" aria-expanded="false"';

    });
```

La verdad no invento más y mejor pregunto a personas que en realidad sepan del tema, agradezco mucho a quien me pueda ayudar. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas ponerle un ID al botón para abrir el menú lateral.

HTML

```
<a id="expandLeftMenu" ...>Abrir</a>
```

JS

```
$(addCitemCart).on("click", () => {
    $(".modal-close").click();
    updateC(customitem, 1, crate);
    $(expandLeftMenu).click();
}
```

Puedes hacer esto sin jQuery también:

```
addCitemCart.addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.querySelector(".modal-close").click();
    updateC(customitem, 1, crate);
    expandLeftMenu.click();
});
```

Para obtener elementos del DOM usando selectores de CSS utiliza `querySelector()` esto es equivalente al `$("selector")` de jQuery, sin embargo, `querySelector()` solo regresará el primer elemento con el selector, usa `querySelectorAll()` para obtener todos los elementos con dicho selector, este método te retornará todos los elementos en un array.

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias